# Write Filename to cell from DIR in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, directory, filenames

I have the macro attached below that loops through files in a Dir and copies data into a master file (which the macro is run from). What I want to do is also write in the master file, the name of the file that the data has been copied from at the top of the column it is pasted into (Cell E5).

Could you please advise...

Sub Import_Data()

```
' PURPOSE: To loop through all Excel files in a user specified folder and perform a set task on them

Dim WB As Workbook
Dim wbThis As Workbook
Dim myPath As String
Dim myFile As String
Dim myExtension As String
Dim FldrPicker As FileDialog

Set wbThis = ActiveWorkbook

' Optimize Macro Speed
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

' Retrieve Target Folder Path From User
MsgBox "Please select Faro Scan Data Folder"

Set FldrPicker = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
With FldrPicker
    .Title = "Select A Target Folder"
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
    myPath = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
End With

' In Case of Cancel
NextCode:
myPath = myPath
If myPath = "" Then GoTo ResetSettings

' Target File Extension (must include wildcard "*")
myExtension = "*.xls"

' Target Path with Ending Extention
myFile = Dir(myPath & myExtension)

' Loop through each Excel file in folder
Do While myFile <> ""

    ' Set variable equal to opened workbook
    Set WB = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=myPath & myFile)

    ' Ensure Workbook has opened before moving on to next line of code
    DoEvents

    ' Copy data from target workbook....
    WB.Activate
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Range("D8:D377").Copy
    wbThis.Activate
    Sheets("Faro Scan Data").Select
    Range("E5").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    ' Insert column for next data set
    Columns("E:E").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight

    ' Format column for new dataset
    Columns("I:I").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Columns("E:E").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, _
    SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    ' Close Workbook
    WB.Close SaveChanges:=False

    ' Ensure Workbook has closed before moving on to next line of code
    DoEvents

    ' Get next file name
    myFile = Dir
Loop

' Message Box when tasks are completed
MsgBox "Task Complete!"

   ResetSettings:
' Reset Macro Optimization Settings
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

MsgBox "Remeber to enter column headings!"

End Sub
```

Comment: It would help if you created a minimal, complete and verifiable example for your problem (see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Also, have you tried anything yourself? (Hint: have a look at the help for the `Dir()` function)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks as if the file name you want is stored in **"myFile"**.
To be sure please add a print to this line

```
myFile = Dir(myPath & myExtension)
Debug.Print myfile
```

and check if the output is actually the string you want.

Try to change

```
Sheets("Faro Scan Data").Select
Range("E5").Select
PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
```

to

```
Sheets("Faro Scan Data").Select
Range("E5").Value = myFile
Range("E6").Select
PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
```

And I am not sure what this line should do:

```
myPath = myPath
```